# Crystal report export to excel : unable to read file

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-9

I am using vb6 program to export  a crystal report to excel sheet.After running the program the exported excel sheet is unreadable. getting the error "Unable to read file"

```
CrxRep.DiscardSavedData
CrxRep.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
CrxRep.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTExcel97

'Input parameter set
CrxRep.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = DestName
CrxRep.ExportOptions.ExcelExportAllPages = True
CrxRep.EnableParameterPrompting = False
CrxRep.ExportOptions.ExcelUseWorksheetFunctions = True
CrxRep.ExportOptions.ExcelUseTabularFormat = True
CrxRep.ExportOptions.ExcelPageBreaks = True
CrxRep.ExportOptions.ExcelTabHasColumnHeadings = True
CrxRep.Export False
```

However this problem occurs only on production server.When I tried to export in dev server it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From where are you trying to read the file ?

If you are logged onto the server and can't read it, that suggests that Excel or perhaps ADO is not installed on the server, but you can answer that by looking at the icon.  If windows recognizes the file type and shows you the Excel icon, then Excel is installed there.

If Excel is installed there, then copy the file to your desktop, or to the dev server, and try to open it there.  If it opens there...the problem is likely a missing component ( perhaps ADO ) on the prod server.

Comment: Crystal report exports the excel file successfully but I cannot open it.This same code is used for 10 other reports.only two of them has got the error.